How to Pass the value for Timeonly datatype for Starttime in API creating in Dotnet
How to pass the value for timeonly datatype for Starttime in API creating in .NET ? As in the database it is storing time in this format 13:00:05.0000000 and when I'm updating it is 12:05:05 in this format at the time of updating time data is not matching what should I do
 public class LocationShifts  
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int LocationId { get; set; }
     public int TimeZoneId { get; set; }

     public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; } // Use TimeOnly
     public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }   // Use TimeOnly
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
     public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
     public int? ModifiedBy{ get; set; }
     public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

     // Navigation properties
     public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
     public virtual CustomTimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }  
}

public class UpdateLocationShiftDTO   
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }   
}

[HttpPut("update-location-shift/{id}")]  
public async Task<IActionResultUpdateLocationShift([FromRoute] int id, UpdateLocationShiftDTO updateLocationShiftDTO)  
{
    try
    {
        var existingLocation = await _locationservice.GetLocationShiftByIdAsync(id);

        if (existingLocation == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Location Shift not found.");
        }

        // Parse the StartTime and EndTime from the DTO
        // Parse the StartTime and EndTime from the DTO, including fractional seconds
        TimeSpan startTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(updateLocationShiftDTO.StartTime, @"hh\:mm\:ss\.ffffff", null); // Ensure parsing fractional seconds
        TimeSpan endTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(updateLocationShiftDTO.EndTime, @"hh\:mm\:ss\.ffffff", null); // Ensure parsing fractional seconds

        // Map the DTO to the domain model (LocationShifts)
        var locationShift = new LocationShifts
            {
                LocationId = updateLocationShiftDTO.LocationId,
                TimeZoneId = updateLocationShiftDTO.TimeZoneId,
                StartTime = startTime, // Set the parsed TimeSpan value
                EndTime = endTime,     // Set the parsed TimeSpan value
                IsActive = updateLocationShiftDTO.IsActive,
            };

        // Update and normalize times
        var updatedLocationShift = await _locationservice.UpdateLocationShiftAsync(id, locationShift);

        if (updatedLocationShift == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Failed to update Location Shift.");
        }

        return Ok(new
                  {
                      success = true,
                      message = "Location shift updated successfully.",
                      data = updatedLocationShift
                  });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new
                               {
                                   success = false,
                                   message = ex.Message,
                                   data = "An unexpected error occurred.",
                                   statusCode = 500
                               });
    }  
}


You can use TimeOnly. SQL type: time(7)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
